# How to unset GEM_HOME

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi my understanding of the terminal is small. I'm trying to install rvm can someone tell me how to unset GEM_HOME? I have a feeling I need to edit some file, but I don't know if its a command line or a file I need to open and comment out.   I'm running Mac OSX 10.14.6 Mojave?

Thank you

```
Joshuas-iMac:~ compy$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.9.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.9/1.29.9.tar.gz.asc
Found PGP signature at: 'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.9/1.29.9.tar.gz.asc',
but no GPG software exists to validate it, skipping.
Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/compy/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/compy/.mkshrc /Users/compy/.profile /Users/compy/.bashrc /Users/compy/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/compy/.profile /Users/compy/.bash_profile /Users/compy/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/compy/.rvm/ is complete.
  * WARNING: you have set GEM_HOME="/Users/compy/.gem/ruby/2.5.1"
     This is conflicting with RVM. Make sure to call:

           unset GEM_HOME

Thanks for installing RVM
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is on the error logs:
`unset GEM_HOME`

On comman line do:

`unset GEM_HOME ; \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`